# I have some trouble to use MailCode to write a mail client

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to write a mail client by using MailCode. When I run this code

```
CTCoreAccount *account = [[CTCoreAccount alloc] init];
CTCoreFolder *folder;
BOOL success=[account connectToServer:@"imap.qq.com" port:143 connectionType:CONNECTION_TYPE_PLAIN authType:IMAP_AUTH_TYPE_PLAIN login:@"1029418889@qq.com" password:@"****"];
if(!success){
    NSLog(@"error");
}

folder = [account folderWithPath:@"INBOX"];
for (CTCoreMessage *msg in [folder messageObjectsFromIndex:0 toIndex:10]) {
       NSLog(@"%@" , msg.subject);
}
```

It would  prompt:

> In the for{} block messageObjectsFromIndex:toIndex not found!

this method is not defined in MailCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `messagesFromSequenceNumber:to:withFetchAttributes:` instead, something like this:

```
for (CTCoreMessage *msg in [folder messagesFromSequenceNumber:1 to:0 withFetchAttributes:CTFetchAttrEnvelope]) {
```